# Easy method to convert Jewish dates to Gregorian dates?

Tags: product-recommendation, calendar, christianity

Does anyone know of a method to make converting Jewish calendar dates to Gregorian calendar dates easy?

Also, is there a program or website that does this?

Comment: go to hebcal.com

Answer (score 5):

I use http://Hebcal.com for this.
 N.B. I did some programming for them.

There is an algorithm that they use, but it's not simple enough to do by hand.

Comment: Note that they offer their code on github.

Comment: @Menachem Yes, and [some of it](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js) is mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sites that convert the calendar automatically such as [hebcal.com](https://www.hebcal.com/) and [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/calendar/1000year_cdo/aid/6225/jewish/Jewish-Civil-Date-Converter.htm) (google is your friend). You can get the lisp conversion code from emacs.

[The Calendar and the Diary](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/emacs/emacs_33.html)

> Emacs provides the functions of a desk calendar, with a diary of
>   planned or past events.
>
> p h
>       Display Hebrew date for selected day (calendar-print-hebrew-date).

[github-misc/Hebrew Calendar/code/cal-hebrew.el](https://github.com/bdenckla/github-misc/blob/master/Hebrew%20Calendar/code/cal-hebrew.el) has the code used in 1209 lines of lisp.

You can see a summary article at [Hebrew Dating](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/calendar-book/papers/IAJGS-Conference.pdf) which points to *Calendrical  Calculations:  The  Millennium  Edition,
  Edward  M.  Reingold  and  Nachum

Dershowitz, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2001.* which gives the algorithms and calculations. There are also one page *universal conversion sheets* such as in

> Calendrical  Tabulations,  1900-2200,   Edward  M.  Reingold  and 
>   Nachum  Dershowitz,   Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2002. 
>   This book (see Fig. 1) gives a set of fully accurate, easy-to-use tabl
>   es that simultaneously display  the  date  on  different  calendars 
>   over a  300-year  period.

Safari shows the lisp code used at 
[Appendix B Lisp Implementation by Edward M. Reingold, Nachum Dershowitz](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/calendrical-calculations-third/9781107702370/AppendixB.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you're looking for, but I feel compelled to point out that [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org), [Jon Skeet](http://Judaism.stackexchange.com/u/5248)'s date/time .NET API, [does](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/calendars) conversions between calendars including Gregorian and Hebrew.